# What's the difference between a redwood and a sequoia?

Tags: trees

I was under the impression they were the same thing, but I have a friend who insists they're two different trees.  What's the difference, and what's the relationship between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the largest and tallest trees in the world.  They are related but not the exactly the same.  See [Sequoioideae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequoioideae).

As far as growing regions go:

Redwood trees primarily grow in Northern California and Oregon along the coast.  See [Redwood National Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redwood_National_and_State_Parks).

Sequoia trees primarily grow in Central California in the Sierra Nevada mountains.  See [Sequoia National Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequoia_National_Park).

Comment: Thanks for the general information on where you'll find them.  Having an idea of which was which when I see it was what I was going for.

Answer (score 5):

They are different. Giant Sequoia, [*Sequoiadendron gigantium*](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=giant%20redwood&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CEYQFjAG&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequoiadendron&ei=FLqQT7P3Gofk6QGI2JiNBA&usg=AFQjCNH-R54VSP8xMMGAlt_KRxPwcAXoeQ), are shorter and more massive. This group contains the worlds largest trees. Redwood, [*Sequoia sempervirens*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequoia_sempervirens), Is the taller, thinner one. This group contains the worlds tallest trees. They are both very long lived.